# Jasmine spec "it" is called before async "beforeAll" calls done

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

i write a Angular 2 application and i want to unittest it with jasmine running by karma.
i am very new to Jasmine and all this stuff, so it is my first angular app at all.
Everything is installed via npm.
Tests running in browser.
I use Karma as test runner.

Versions:

- Jasmine: 2.4.1
- Karma: 1.5.0
- Chrome: 56.0.2924
- OS: Mac OS X 10.12.3

The Problem:
I created a suite, as follows:

```
describe('Service with asyncCall', () => {
        beforeAll((done) => {
             jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 8000;

            new Service().asyncCall().then((result) => {
                        console.log(result);
                        done();
                    }
                );
            }
        );

        it(
            'should be true',
            () => {
                console.log('test');
                expect(true).toEqual(true);
            }
        );
}
```

The asyncCall is as follows:

```
asyncCall() {
    var out = new Promise(
       (resolve) => {
            setTimeout(
                () => {
                    resolve('success');
                },
                2000
            );
        }
    );

    return out;
}
```

I expect the output to be something like

```
...
success
test
...
```

But the actual output in the Browser console is

test
success
Also the test is failing with the following message(s)

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Please can anybody help me out, or pointing in the right direction.
And sorry for my english is not so well...

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Just to be shure, that this is not the problem, i set the jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL up to 8000, but it did not help.

Comment: But jsfiddle is working https://jsfiddle.net/9zmt8x8b/

Comment: It works. Try to remove all redundant code and check it

Comment: Thanks for your comments. When i played around with the timeout value in the asyncCall method, i found out, that it has to be less than or equal to 999. From 1000 ms on the described error occurs. And as i noted above the jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL is set to 8000.
Is there another value i am missing, that is set to 1000 ms?

Comment: Oh and @yurzui: for any reason, i can not open the jsfiddle.net link; it loads and loads...

Comment: Ok i think i found the problem. To start with angular 2 i cloned the QuickStart Seed. As a newbie i have no idea what the most files inside are for, but now i found  jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000; in the karma-test-shim.js Changing this value in my code seems to have no effect, but changing the value here solved my problem. YEAY! :-)

Comment: @phts : regarding the jsfiddle - Jasmine 2.4.1 - says "No specs found" - any hints?

Comment: @KarolDepka Probably you have a syntax error somewhere. Check the console. My jsfiddle uses ES6, and maybe your browser doesn't support it?

Comment: @phts - thanks, but I'm using the jsfiddle url from the comment: jsfiddle.net/9zmt8x8b - Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: @phts Btw, Dobry Wieczór z Malagi, jak się żyje w Krakowie? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the problem. To start with angular 2 I cloned the QuickStart Seed.

As a newbie, I have no idea what the most files inside are for, but now I found `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;` in the `karma-test-shim.js`.

Changing this value in my code seems to have no effect, but changing the value here solved my problem.